# Returning an array of byteArray objects from database for amfphp

Tags: flash, arrays, remoting, amfphp

Working with amfphp.

I can return one row bytearray object, but every row will contain a new bytearray object that I want to return to flash.

Multidimensional arrays are converted to bytearrays then sent to the database table "ba" and on return I've only been able to reload either the first or last result.

Example code:

```
public function read(){

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");


for($i=0;$i<mysql_num_rows( $result );$i++){


$rows[$i] =  new ByteArray($result[$i]['ba']);

};

return $rows;
```

Answer (score 0):

for anyone who stumbles on this same hair puller-outerer. THERE'S A BUG IN THE AMF bytearray function and can be patched with this;

http://piggymemo.blogspot.ca/2010/03/patch-for-amfphp-amf3-bytearray.html

and the php for it ended up looking like this;

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
$rows = array();

while ($entry = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {

$bar = new ByteArray($entry->ba);
$rows[] = $bar;

}

return $rows;
```

thank god for that! time to celebrate by getting back to work!

Answer (score 0):

or, in amfPHP v2 and later, this should work out of the box, but with 
Amfphp_Core_Amf_Types_ByteArray
instead of 
ByteArray.